# How do I get an OpenVPN client in OpwnWrt to connect to an OpenVPN hidden service?

Tags: socks, transparent-proxy, openvpn

Using Whonix 7 as a model, I'm attempting to use OpenWrt 12.09 VMs as both Tor gateway and workspace. In particular, I want to use these pairs of OpenWrt VMs to establish OpenVPN tunnels through Tor. In one pair, the Tor gateway has a hidden service pointing to an OpenVPN server in the workspace. In the other pair, there's an OpenVPN client in the workspace.

The OpenVPN-server pair seems to be working. I can connect to it using an OpenVPN client in a Whonix workstation, using either OpenVPN's socks-port option with Tor's SocksPort, or Tor's TransPort without the socks-port option.

I've tested the Tor gateway of the OpenVPN-client pair using a Whonix workstation VM, with required changes in eth0 configuration. An OpenVPN client in the Whonix workstation connects using OpenVPN's socks-port option, so I know that SocksPort is working in the OpenWrt Tor gateway.

However, `TransPort` in the OpenWrt Tor gateway seems broken, because an OpenVPN client in the Whonix workstation VM doesn't connect without OpenVPN's socks-port option. Perhaps OpenWrt isn't routing properly, through incompatibility or misconfiguration. Or maybe it's because the OpenWrt repository doesn't have the latest Tor release (0.2.2.39 being the latest in the OpenWrt repo).

Using the complete OpenVPN-client pair, an OpenVPN client won't connect even with the socks-proxy option. I get the error `Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in client0.conf:4: socks-proxy (2.2.2)`. Perhaps there's something broken in the OpenVPN port to OpenWrt.

I see three paths:

1. fix TransPort in my OpenWrt Tor gateway;
2. get socks-proxy working for OpenVPN in OpenWrt; and
3. use tsocks with OpenVPN in OpenWrt.

Which path is the most promising?